# Sending a Javascript table to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, post, html-table, row

I'm not good in JavaScript and I wish someone could help.

The issue is this:

```
$(function(){
$('.preview-add-button').click(function(){            
   var form_data = {};
    form_data["concept"] = "café Noir";
    form_data["status"] = parseFloat(10).toFixed(2);
    form_data["description"] = 1;           
    form_data["amount"] = parseFloat(10 * form_data["description"]).toFixed(2);        
    form_data["remove-row"] = '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>';
    var row = $('<tr></tr>');
    $.each(form_data, function( type, value ) {
        $('<td class="input-'+type+'"></td>').html(value).appendTo(row);
    });
    $('.preview-table > tbody:last').append(row); 
    calc_total();   

});
```

The JavaScript works perfectly but I need to send the table to a php so that it can be stored in database.

The complete source code is from [bootsnipp](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/payment-form-with-total-preview).

Comment: send form_data through an ajax call, you can use [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: I know it can be done with ajax jauery jason but how

Comment: Oh wow. There are nearly 20 million results for "send data ajax" on Google. Who would have guessed.

Answer (score 0):

Modify to your taste and add this to your code

```
$.post('your_post_url',
{
    data: value,
    data: value
},
function(data)
{
    //what to do when ajax request completes
})
```

Comment: could you please explain moor